# Whatsapp blocked by justice

Tags: internet, international

Here in Brazil we have this case: justice has asked Facebook for some data from a drug dealer whatsapp account. Facebook denied. Now, justice has blocked Whatsapp service in all the country as a penalty..

My question is: does the government has the right to obligate a international company break their security policy?

Comment: How does requesting an user's personal data break their security policy? Anyway, Whatapp's ToS clearly state that "**We may** collect and **release Personally Identifiable Information** and/or non-personally-identifiable information **if required to do so by law**, or in the good-faith belief that such action is necessary to comply with state and federal laws (such as U.S. Copyright Law), international law **or respond to a court order, subpoena, or search warrant or equivalent**, or where in our reasonable belief, an individual’s physical safety may be at risk or threatened" (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 1):

Think of this another way:  ExxonMobil is an international corporation.  Why should they have to comply with the sovereign laws of some small country they do business within?

Comment: If ExxonMobil had an office in such country, why wouldn't it have to comply with its laws? I might be interpreting this wrong though (IANAL).

Comment: @mgibsonbr that's the point:  of course the local sovereign laws are binding!  Where what's app gets away with it is in the fact that the servers and data don't actually reside within the sovereign boundaries

Comment: You might be right: even though Facebook has office(s) in Brazil, the servers themselves that hold our user's data are [probably] not here, which would be a problem enforcing the court order.